# Direction of electric field of a spherically symmetric charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism

Why must the direction of electric field of a spherically symmetric charge distribution  be entirely radial?

Comment: Same question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73027/why-is-the-radial-direction-the-preferred-one-in-spherical-symmetry

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it doesn't.

This is only the case given we have a spherically symetric  distribution whilst also having the condition that

$$\nabla × \vec{E} = 0$$

And also having the boundary condition that the fields vanish at infinity!(homogenous solution is zero)

Look into the definition of the divergence for a point source, and you  intuitively see that the sum of these elements in a spherical manner, will also produce spherical symetry, provided this divergence is the only source of field production

This is also provided the fields vanish at infinity aswell. The spherical symmetry   can be seen via the solution to poissons equation in electrostatics where $\rho$ is spherical.

$$\nabla^2 V = - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$$

When in doubt, just do the math for spherical distributions! No assumptions necessary (apart from the assumption E=0 at infinity)