# Proof that spherically symmetric charge density yields electric potential with the same symmetry

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, potential, voltage

it is intuitively clear to me that a spherically symmetric charge density $\rho(\vec{x}) = \rho(r)$ generates a electric potential $\phi(r)$ with the same symmetry.
However I really struggle to formalize / proof this. Every resource I could find stated that it can be "easily seen".

I tried using $\Delta \phi = -\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho$ with the Laplace-Operator in spherical coordinates, to show that $\partial_{\varphi}\phi = 0, \partial_{\theta}\phi = 0$

Also, I tried using the explicit formula $\phi(\vec{x}) = - \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \int d^3y \frac{\rho(\vec{y})}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|}$, however it always ended in an overcomplicated mess.

It seems to me that I am missing a simple elementary proof of this, especially because my approach would not easily generalize to other symmetries (e.g. cylindrical). Do you know a simple (short) proof?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712106/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a solution $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ that satisfies$$\nabla^2\phi(\mathbf{x})=-\frac{\rho(\mathbf{x})}{\epsilon_0}$$ for some spherically symmetric $\rho$ then we can do a coordinate transform $$\mathbf{x}\to R~\mathbf{x}$$ which yields the equation $$\nabla^2\phi(R~\mathbf{x})=-\frac{\rho(\mathbf{x})}{\epsilon_0}$$ since both the laplacian and the charge density are invariant under rotations. Subtracting the two equations from each other and defining $\psi=\phi(\mathbf{x})-\phi(R~\mathbf{x})$ gives $$\nabla^2\psi=0$$ which together with the fact that $\psi\to0$ for large $|\mathbf{x}|$ means that $\psi$ must be zero everywhere.

Comment: Note, however, that if we do not require $\psi \to 0$ as $|\mathbf{x}| \to \infty$ then it is not true that a spherically symmetric charge distribution must have a spherically symmetric potential.

Comment: Only when the boundary conditions for $\psi$ at infinity are not spherically symmetric.

Comment: What I meant was, $\psi$ can only be nonzero at infinity if the boundary conditions for $\phi$ are not spherically symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

> Proof that spherically symmetric charge density yields electric potential with the same symmetry...

> Also, I tried using the explicit formula $\phi(\vec{x}) = - \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \int d^3y \frac{\rho(\vec{y})}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|}$, however it always ended in an overcomplicated mess.

This is a homework-like question and should be closed. But I will get you started...

Starting from your equation quoted above, write down the expression for $\phi(R\vec x)$, where $R$ is an arbitrary rotation matrix. Then make a change of variables for the dummy variable of integration $\vec y = R\vec z$, and also note that $\det(R)=1$ so the measure doesn't change. Then use the fact that $\rho(R\vec z) = \rho(\vec z)$, since the charge density is spherically symmetric. Compare the far LHS to the far RHS and you should be done.

As a second alternative, you can also solve this problem by expanding
$$
\frac{1}{|\vec x - \vec y|} 
$$
in terms of Legendre polynomials.

You will again see that only the spherically symmetric piece remains due to the orthogonality of Legendre polynomials.